# Disabling package updates for custom-built Vim

Tags: 14.04, package-management, ubuntu-mate

I built Vim from source and installed it via `checkinstall`, but whenever I run `sudo apt-get update`, it lists `vim`, `vim-common` and `vim-runtime` along with the other things I do want to update. When I update other packages, it installs the Vim-related updates along with those, which messes the Vim I set up.

For what it's worth, I also built and installed Mercurial the same way, but I don't get prompted for updates to the `mercurial-common` and `mercurial` packages.

Is there a way to tell the software updater application to exclude Vim from the updates I get?

Comment: Why do you build software from source, when there is same software in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6: They usually have older versions. If I can find a PPA which supplies a more recent version, I use that instead.

Comment: PPA is much more handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed software from source, you can remove or hold the native Ubuntu packages.

To remove vim, you can run

```
sudo apt-get remove vim
```

But this can break some dependencies.

As an alternative you can just hold it from getting updates by

```
sudo apt-mark hold vim
```

Comment: I did do this (`sudo apt-get remove vim-tiny vim-common vim-runtime`) before I built Vim. I will try the `apt-mark` option and see. Thanks.